# Freemarker displays int value as double value(e.g. prints 0 as 0.00)

Tags: freemarker

I am trying to write a freemarker template file having information about a table.

I have written '${noRows}' in the template for table rows count.
The noRows is a int  value:

```
int noOfRows = myTable.getNumRows();
data.put("noRows", noOfRows);
```

The noOfRows is always an integer value but in the output file it is displayed as double value with ".00" appended to it.

How can I display the value as integer only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value is indeed an integer, all you should need to do is

```
${noOfRows?string}
```

You can also use the Java decimal number format syntax:

```
${noOfRow?string["0"]}
```

Reference: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html#ref_builtin_string_for_number

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, your `number_format` setting is set to `0.00` or like. (FreeMarker doesn't care about `Integer` VS `Double` when formatting numbers. It just have a single numerical type, and it formats all of them according to that setting.) Check it wherever FreeMarker is configured. As last resort, you can also set this setting in the template like `<#setting number_format="0.##">`. Last not least, as "sev" said, you can specify the format at each place individually.